# Line in Wxmaxima not high enough to show exponent of exponent [solved]

Tags: wxmaxima

[image]when I type: in Wxmaxima:

exp(-x^2/2);

the result shown then in Wxmaxima cuts off the exponent of x, i.e. from 2 I see only the base line.

I am running on Lubuntu 20.4:

```
_wxMaxima version: 19.07.0
using wxWidgets version: wxWidgets 3.0.4
Maxima version: 5.43.2
Maxima build date: 2020-02-21 05:22:38
Host type: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
System type: BSD BSD NIL
Lisp implementation type: GNU Common Lisp (GCL)
Lisp implementation version: GCL 2.6.12_
```

Is there anything I can do to get the whole expression shown in Wxmaxima?
I have asked the same question at:

https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima/discussions/1521

but it looks as if there is not much traffic.

Thanks
Karl

**Edit: added picture.**

**Edit:** works ok with wxmaxima 21.02.0-DevelopmentSnapshot from
ppa:peterpall/wxmaxima-nightlies

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what you've seeing, either here or on the github issue? When I try `exp(-x^2/2)`, I see the whole expression; I'm working with wxMaxima 20.11.1 on macOS. Perhaps it is a platform-dependent problem.

Comment: @Robert Dodier,  I added a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

The bug should now be resolved in wxMaxima's code and the bugfix is included in the installer that can be found at https://wolfgang.dautermann.at/maxima/nightlybuild/. If you install both the Nightly build and a release on the same system make sure you start the right wxMaxima, though.

Comment: thanks for your help. However I am using Lubuntu as I wrote and AFAIS the nightly build is only for Windows. Do you think that it also ok in: https://code.launchpad.net/~peterpall/+archive/ubuntu/wxmaxima-nightlies, the build for Ubuntu?

Comment: It should be fixed Tiere, too, by now.

Comment: Yes, it is, see my edit to the question. Thanks.